# Tkinter callback with OOP appoach

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I have got a class with a callback method, which calls multiple other methods, because if I understand it correctly, you can not pass arguments to button clicks.

This is my callback method:

```
class MainApplication(tk.Frame):

....
def callback(self):
    browsed_path = self.browse_button()
    if(os.path.isdir(browsed_path)):
        self.download_file_from_server(local_path=browsed_path, multiple_folders = v.get())
        self.processing(local_path = browsed_path, tk=tk)
        self.wrong_files(local_path = browsed_path)
....
```

I use this button the following way:

```
button1 = tk.Button(text='Wähle einen Pfad und starte Download', command = MainApplication.callback, bg='brown', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(300, 140, window=button1)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
callback() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Well I guess I have to use self as other argument to refer to my actual class.

Comment: use `self.callback` instead of `MainApplication.callback`

Comment: if you want to run function with arguments then you can use `command=lambda:self.callback(arguments)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory. If you are calling a class function from outside the class, you need to instantiate it first:

```
main_app = MainApplication()
button1 = tk.Button(text='...', command=main_app.callback, ...)
```

If you are using it from within the class, use it as `command=self.callback`

And you **CAN DEFINITELY** pass arguments to button clicks using `lambda`:

```
command = lambda: self.callback(list of arguments)
```